# Does /ŋz/ at the end of the word sound [ŋgs] with a hard 'g'?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, british-english, phonetics

The combination **ŋ** + ***-s*** in words like *things, songs, sings* etc.

Is there a hard 'g' sound between ŋ and the *-s* (/z/)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by soft g. Do you mean as in words like general?

Comment: No, sorry, I have just edited it.. I mean hard 'g' like 'rag'..
because it seems to me that I hear 'hard g' sound in words like 'songs - things' especially when 'ngs' comes at the end of the sentence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In standard accents of English (Southern Standard British English and General American), there isn't a hard g (/g/) between **ŋ** and the plural suffix *-s* (/-z/), so it's simply **ŋz**. But in some British accents such as West Midlands, some varieties of Scottish English (and presumably some American accents), people do pronounce the sequence **ŋz** as **ŋgz**.